# Does water have the same surface tension at same temperature but different volume?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I'm making an experiment and it is written in my older questions.

Now, my question is -
Does water have the same surface tension at same temperature but different volume?

Comment: I've merged your two accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking if the surface tension of water depends on temperature and not volume.  The answer is yes as long as the volume is "large enough" so that most of the surface area of the water is flat.

The reason for this is that the interactions of water molecules with each other are very short-ranged.  Thus a given water molecule has no idea what is going on 100 water molecules away.   So the volume of water doesn't mater as long as it contains a very large number of molecules.